# Can't move mouse with touchpad

Tags: input, mouse, manjaro, xinput

As the title suggests, my touchpad won't move my mouse. I am therefore unable to select outputs of my commands, but I am able to take screenshots of windows. (Luckily I am used to using keyboard shortcuts)

I have no clue what caused this. I have recently updated my kernel from linux52 to linux53 and linux54. Falling back to either of those versions from linux54 hasn't helped. I have also recently been playing around with a Wacom tablet, using `xsetwacom`, but I believe my mouse has worked after this.

I know it's not a hardware issue, as `libinput debug-events` correctly detects my finger running over the trackpad:

[image: debug-events]

The output of 40-libinput.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf is the following. I can't see any error there.

[image: 40-libinput.conf]

I tried blacklisting the i2c_hid, as suggested in the following [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607425/ubuntu-14-04-does-not-see-a-touchpad-on-my-dell-inspiron-14-3000-laptop), but to no avail. It fixed an error claiming there was a duplicate mouse, which it decided to ignore. I thought this would help.

[image: blacklist and xinput list]

What is surprising is that I can click. I can't scroll or move the mouse, though. My trackpad lists the following settings. To my surprise, there is no Accel Speed there, and I can't manually set it with `xinput --set-prop 14 'libinput Accel Speed' 1.0`, as I need to specify the type and format. I don't know what these are supposed to be, and I don't know if the acceleration is the issue. I read that having a negative value would cause the mouse to never move, though.

[image: xinput properties]

Do you have any suggestions as to what to do? What does libinput do with the events after receiving them?

EDIT: Removing the `blacklist i2c_hid` from the modprobe returns the following Xorg log:

[image: Xorg log without blacklist]

Answer (score 0):

Making a copy of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf` into my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` folder, and commenting out the `Option "Ignore" "on"` line fixed it.

Had to `sudo pkill X` after changing it, of course. A reboot would also do the trick.